# User-configurable signalling mechanism in Django

Tags: django, schema, signals, notifications, webhooks

*The question here is whether something like this already exists or, if not, whether there's a better way to achieve it than what I describe below.*

I need to allow an arbitrary Principal (User, Group, Site Admin) to add `Event Sink`s (like email addresses, [Webhook](http://webhooks.org/) URLs, etc.) to the system (through the web interface) and, for each one, specify which kinds of `<Event Source, Event Type>` should be sent to it. Since I'm doing this for [ReviewBoard](http://www.review-board.org/), I'll give a concrete example with a hypothetical implementation:

1. John creates a new `event_sink` (a
   webhook), identified by `postbin1`;
2. John specifies that `postbin1` will receive events of type `publish` on `ReviewRequest`s (a class-level `subscription` -- the `source_id` is unspecified);
3. When a new `review_request` is created, the `Event Manager`, lists (through a JOIN with `subscriptions`) all `event_sinks` interested in `ReviewRequest`s and creates a (instance-level) `subscription` binding them as a listener to their particular `event_type` (the name of a django signal) of interest *and* to the specific `review_request`;
4. When that `review_request` gets published, the `Event Manager` (who listens to the `publish` signal) lists all `event_sinks` interested in that `review_request` instance and the `publish` signal and dispatches the signal parameters to their `sink` method.
5. The Webhook `event_sink` marshals the data however pleases it and POSTs it to its URL.

This is the schema I thought of:
[alt text http://bayimg.com/image/aadgoaacd.jpg](http://bayimg.com/image/aadgoaacd.jpg)

I'm about to start implementing this myself, but I just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel. Couldn't find anything on Google. Ready-to-use package names, half-way package names that will help me, and/or criticism to my DIY approach are all welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-notification](http://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/tree/master) by James Tauber gets you a good chunk of the way there.  I would love to see that app mature if you're willing to work off of that codebase it would be great.